# In panda python how do I "blacklist" or "whitelist" numbers in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, and I want to add a new column to the df with the first allowed numbers in df1, but only as many as are in each group, when it starts again at 1 it needs to look at the first number in Allowed_numbers.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Allowed_numbers': [3,4,5,6,8,9,12,15,17,24,28,29,30]})
df = pd.DataFrame({'order_out': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
```

and want this:

```
      order_y  y_goal
0         1       3
1         2       4
2         3       5
3         4       6
4         5       8
5         6       9
6         7      12
7         8      15
8         9      17
9         1       3
10        2       4
11        3       5
12        4       6
13        5       8
14        6       9
15        7      12
16        8      15
17        9      17
...
```

I have tried a few things

```
df= bags.sort_values(['order_out'])
df.loc[:, 'y_goal'] = pd.Series(Allowed_numbers)
```

and get this

```
    order_out y_goal
0         1     3.0
1         2     4.0
2         3     5.0
3         4     6.0
4         5     8.0
5         6     9.0
6         7    12.0
7         8    15.0
8         9    17.0
9         1    24.0
10        2    28.0
11        3    29.0
12        4    30.0
13        5     NaN
14        6     NaN
15        7     NaN
16        8     NaN
17        9     NaN
...
```

I was also considering some kind of mapping numbers against eachother, since 1 in order_out will always be 3 in y_goals. the order_out might also have different lengths of number row, not always up to 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `order_out` as an index to df1 (we subtract 1 to convert from 1-indexing to 0-indexing):

```
y_goal = df1['Allowed_numbers'][df['order_out'] - 1]
```

Now we can reset the index on y_goal and neatly merge the two columns:

```
df['y_goal'] = y_goal.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a list comprehension here:

```
df['y_goal'] = [df1['Allowed_numbers'][x - 1] for x in df['order_out']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**`DataFrame.merge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) which you can match a column to index of other data frame. However, since `order_out` does not start at zero, use a temporary column to be dropped after merging.

```py
df_result = (df.assign(key=lambda x: x["order_out"].sub(1))
               .merge(df1, left_on="key", right_index=True, how="left")
               .drop("key", axis="columns")
            )
```

Output

```py
df_result
    order_out  Allowed_numbers
0           1                3
1           2                4
2           3                5
3           4                6
4           5                8
5           6                9
6           7               12
7           8               15
8           9               17
9           1                3
10          2                4
11          3                5
12          4                6
13          5                8
14          6                9
15          7               12
16          8               15
17          9               17
18          1                3
19          2                4
20          3                5
21          4                6
22          5                8
23          6                9
24          7               12
25          8               15
26          9               17
```

Comment: Works very well even when you have None in the "order_out". Thanks, that is what I needed now.